# Broken airflow upgrade_check command. Outputs "Please install apache-airflow-upgrade-check distribution from PyPI to perform upgrade checks"

Tags: airflow

Currently running airflow 1.10.15. Wanted to perform some tests before upgrading to 2+. So installed `pip install apache-airflow-upgrade-check` in the scheduler pod which installed successfully. So I then run the command `airflow upgrade_check` but it did not return the results that I expected. It's giving me this output in terminal

```
[2021-06-15 21:02:38,637] {{settings.py:233}} DEBUG - Setting up DB connection pool (PID 15732)
[2021-06-15 21:02:38,637] {{settings.py:300}} DEBUG - settings.prepare_engine_args(): Using pool settings. pool_size=5, max_overflow=10, pool_recycle=1800, pid=15732
[2021-06-15 21:02:38,735] {{sentry.py:179}} DEBUG - Could not configure Sentry: No module named 'blinker', using DummySentry instead.
[2021-06-15 21:02:38,754] {{__init__.py:45}} DEBUG - Cannot import  due to  doesn't look like a module path
[2021-06-15 21:02:38,916] {{cli_action_loggers.py:42}} DEBUG - Adding <function default_action_log at 0x7f9a637c3a70> to pre execution callback

Please install apache-airflow-upgrade-check distribution from PyPI to perform upgrade checks

[2021-06-15 21:02:39,266] {{settings.py:310}} DEBUG - Disposing DB connection pool (PID 15732)
```

What am I missing?

Updated 6/16/2021: I verified if the package was installed, I did see the package in list:

```
...
apache-airflow               1.10.15
apache-airflow-upgrade-check 1.3.0
apispec                      1.3.3
argcomplete                  1.12.2
...
```

Comment: I found this in airflow github: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/14137
Seems like it is fixed but not yet merged?

Answer (score 5):

The problem I had was the container was running as a non-root user which was defined in `Dockerfile`. If I install the package in the running pod, it will install in some local directory and when executing the `airflow upgrade_check` command, it cannot find the package. To work-around this issue, I need to add the packages in `Dockerfile` so it will be included when creating the docker image.